# Create a string using date function, with preceding zero on day and month

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, date

I am trying to create a date in VBA.
I want it to display as 13.04.2018 for today's date.

However, I can currently only get it to display as 13.4.2018

How do i include a preceding zero on days and months with a single digit ?

I have currently got to:

```
stDateDay = Day(Date)
stDateMonth = Month(Date)
stDateYear = Year(Date)
stDateFull = stDateDay & "." & stDateMonth & "." & stDateYear
```

Comment: `strDateFull = format (Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")`?

Comment: Searching for "[microsoft-excel] date format" brings up 1148 posts.  The answer to your question is likely among those.

Comment: @TomBrunberg - that's a few less than a Google search for "vba date format" which gives 1.8 million options, the 2nd of which is MS's own docs... ;)

Comment: Yeah @Free there's plenty of too much :)

Comment: @Berend Thanks, post as answer and i can accept as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format a date (or any other value) in VBA, you can use the `Format` function. For example:

```vb
strDateFull = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

The second parameter is a format string that can be either a predefined  format name (`General Date`, `Long Date`, `Medium Date` or `Short Date`), or a format specifier including symbols such as `dd`, `mm` or `yy`.

For a full list of symbols see the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Answer (score 0):

simply You can try this:

```
Range("A1").Value = Format(StDateFull, "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

*Or you can also Format the Cell or Range of Cells before you pass StDateFull value to it/them like:*

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"

Range("A:C").Select
Format$ ("dd.mm.yyyy")

Range("A1").value = stDateFull
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, i am not using the sting for a Cell Value, Thanks anyway

Comment: Then where you want to use it?

Comment: stDateFull = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")      ActiveSheet.Name = stDateFull

Comment: i got there in the end

Comment: Nice, but ultimately you use it somewhere in the sheet !!

Comment: Are you trying to rename the Sheet Name?

Comment: Yes, each day i will be creating a new sheet, and wanted to name it with the day it was created etc. hence not needing Range.Value